# Rspec model testing 'validate_presence_of' throws Module::DelegationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my specs

```
describe 'Do sth..' do
  it { should validate_presence_of :some_attribute }    
end
```

In my model I have
But I am getting

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :sub_order, inverse_of: :order, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :some_attribute

  delegate(
    :some_attributes1,
    to: :sub_order
  )
end
```

> Module::DelegationError:
>          Order#some_attributes1 delegated to sub_order.some_attributes1, but sub_order is nil: #

Can any help me please? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error says: `sub_order` is `nil` so method call cannot be delegated there. You have two options:

1. Ensure that `sub_order` is not nil (e.g. by overriding the getter)
2. Use `.delegate` with `:allow_nil` option

> `:allow_nil` - if set to true, prevents a `Module::DelegationError` from being raised

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Comment: I am just validating the presence of, but I should not get `Module::DelegationError`. Actually I am just validating presence of `some_attribute` but I am getting error from `some_attribute1`, How is that related?

Comment: You should. If you delegate it to other object and this object is `nil`, error should be raised.

Comment: Thats correct, but delegate and validation are happening on completely two different attributes.

Comment: Maybe you have another validation on `some_attribute1` and matcher calls `valid?` (not sure).

Comment: Post full stacktrace, we'll see :)

Comment: Finally I spotted the errors, I have a `before_validation` callback. That was triggering the delegation. Thanks for the help any way.